# How to create custom error messages in APEX?

Tags: oracle, error-handling

I would like to replace standard ORA-xxxxx messages with custom ones in Oracle Application Express. For example instead of this:

[image: apex screenshot]

to have something like "You have left some fields blank, try again".
What is a best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Apex specifically, use validations. You can specify them per field or use a custom one that checks all the fields at once.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23903_01/doc/doc.41/e21674/bldr_validate.htm#BABCDBDE